# Why the browser crashes using this function in for loop?

Tags: javascript

I've tried different variations, using this (topMag) function. What i want, with the function is, when i call the getElem function for an example with all the paragraphs, i want the topMag to count every paragraph's height from the top of the paragraph to the top of the document. Please someone explain to me, what is happening here when the function is called, and how to solve it.

```js
var elem, celElem, elemTop = [], elemMag = [], elemBot = [], elemCent = [], winTop, winMag, winBot, winCent, i;

function getElem(el, cEl, fn){
 if(el.length === undefined){
  el = [el];
  cEl = [cEl]
 };
 elem = el;
 celElem = cEl;
   for (i = 0; i<elem.length; i++){ 
 elemTop[i] = 0;
 elemMag[i] = elem[i].offsetHeight;
 elemBot[i] = elemTop[i]+elemMag[i];
 elemCent[i] = elemTop[i]+(elemMag[i]/2);
    topMag(elem[i], i);
 }
 winTop = window.pageYOffset;
 winMag = window.innerHeight;
 winBot = winTop+winMag;
 winCent = winTop+(winMag/2);

};
//the reason, why i need x: when the function is executed,
//i want to remain elem[i] to elem[i], not the body 
function topMag(x, i){
 elem[i] = x
 if (getComputedStyle(elem[i]).position === "fixed"){
  elemTop[i] = elem[i].offsetTop;
 }
 else{
  do{
   elemTop[i] += elem[i].offsetTop;
   elem[i] = elem[i].offsetParent;
  }
  while(elem[i] != "[object HTMLBodyElement]");
  elem[i] = x;
 }
};
```

Comment: At no point are you incrementing `i` within your `do...while` loop.

Comment: `elem[ï]` will be an HTMLBodyElement, but never the String `"[object HTMLBodyElement]"`